# Compression of neighborhood graph

Tags: algorithm, geometry, compression, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I have a *huge* neighboorhood graph (~100M vertices) where vertices that are "near" each other have an edge. Obviously neighbouring vertices have many neighours in common.

### Why no spatial index?

You can think of it as a geometrical problem. But in reality some edges might not exist because a few more criteria than only geometry must be checked to fulfill the "neighour"-condition. The other condition is very expensive to check. But it is guaranteed that vertices that are geometrically far from each other will certainly not be neighbours. Geometrical proximity is a necessary condition for a neighbor-edge.

Hence, this is not a social graph. This graph is only locally dense. It has dense subgraphs.

Is there a way to exploit this knowledge to compress the graph? At the moment it's way to big to fit in memory.

### Example

In this example all neighborhood-edges are drawn as solid lines whereas edges that are dashed show only those vertices that are "near" each other not no neighbours (an other criterion is not met). The dashed edges do not exist. Only the information about the solid edges is relevant.
[image: neighborhood graph]

### Question

How can I compress the information about the neighbor-edges?

The query will be: Give me all neighbouring vertices for a specific vertex.

Comment: But how do you store this graph? And what are you going to do with it? Adjacency lists have no significant overhead.

Comment: But adjacency-lists of neighbouring vertices are nearly identical (see vertices 27 and 28). I want to exploit this information to compress further.

Comment: You can try to add some clusterization, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: The problem is that there are not a few clusters but O(n) clusters all overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that simple compression scheme is possible  -
choose an arbitrary node
make bread-first search with depth of few levels
check for neighbours with similar adjacency lists
mark them as secondary
write base node and difference for them
when you meet node with too far adjacency list, organize new base node with full list.

But what is this graph intended for? Any compression will make operations slower...

```
 Node: 
     Base node (for base node: null, for secondary: base node (number or address)
     List: True adj. list for base node
           RemoveList, AddList for secondary node
```

when size of RemoveList + AddList becomes comparable with size of base list, make new base

Some [close ideas found](http://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/2/3/1031/pdf)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "mark them as secondary"?

Comment: Sketch of possible approach added

Comment: I'm still experimenting with this -- for example I'm allowing to have base-nodes that have base-nodes themselves (limited to a certain depth to guarantee O(1) for decompressing edges). But I really like the idea!